# Visual Studio and SQL Error The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

It tells me the error "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open." whenever I click the add button. I am new at Visual Studio 2010 and Sql Server 2008, help or any advice will do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MRP.SupplierMaterial
{
    public partial class Add : Form
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon());

        public Add()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       void GetSuppliers()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CompanyName, ContactPerson, Phone, Mobile, Status, DateAdded, DateModified FROM Suppliers";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Suppliers");
            cmbSupplierID.DataSource = ds.Tables["Suppliers"];
            cmbSupplierID.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
            cmbSupplierID.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
            con.Close();
        }

       void GetMaterials()
       {
           con.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
           cmd.Connection = con;
           cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Materials.MaterialID, " +
               "Materials.Name + ' (' + UnitID.UnitMeasure + ')' AS MaterialName " +
               "FROM Materials INNER JOIN UnitID ON Materials.UnitID = UnitID.UnitID";
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
           da.Fill(ds, "Materials");
           cmbMaterialID.DataSource = ds.Tables["Materials"];
           cmbMaterialID.DisplayMember = "MaterialName";
           cmbMaterialID.ValueMember = "MaterialID";
           con.Close();
       }

       private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           con.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
           cmd.Connection = con;
           cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SupplierMaterials VALUES (@SupplierID, @MaterialID);";
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", cmbSupplierID.SelectedValue);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaterialID", cmbMaterialID.SelectedValue);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();
       }

       private void Add_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           GetMaterials();
           GetSuppliers();

       }

    }
}
```

Comment: please post your stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems one of  `GetSuppliers()` ` is not executed till the part where you set

```
con.Close()
```

You have two alternatives:

1.Open the connection only once and use it in every method without closing it and close it on `Application.Exit`:

```
     public Add()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                con.Open();
            }
.........
 private void Add_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         con.Close();
       }
```

2. Set this check in every attempt to open con:

   if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
          {
               con.Open();
          }

Answer (score 0):

[SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class implements `IDisposable`. So you use `Dispose()` method directly. The efficient way of doing is with the `using` block

To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside 
    of a `using block`, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that 
    the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
{
// Do something 
}// Here it will automatically call Dispose()
```

You will still need to open the connection but don't need to close it because as I mentioned the `Dispose()` method will take care of the object at the end of the using block

Answer (score 0):

```
Using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
{
 //Your rest of the code inside here.
}
```

This take care of closing your connection but you will have to manually open it. con.Open();

Answer (score 0):

Put below condition  instead of con.open();

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
        con.Open();
   }
```